# How can I "space between" SVG text that also has an associated key/icon?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm doing the following in a React component:

```
return (
    <svg width={1000} height={50}>
      {observations.map((obs, i) => {

        // calculate evenly spaced point for each observation
        const x = (1000 / observations.length) * i + 1000 / observations.length / 2;

        return (
          <g key={i} transform={`translate(${i * 150}, 0)`}>
            <g transform={`translate(10, 10)`}>
              <ObservationKeyMarker {...obs} />
            </g>
            <text x={20} y={15} fill="black" stroke="none">
              {obs.label}
            </text>
          </g>
        );
      })}
    </svg>
  );
```

but my text labels are very different in length.

[image]

I have calculated the "middle points" where I'd like to place the labels but unsure how to do that in conjunction with the colored key marker (also in svg)

**Update**

Flexbox provides a `justify-content: space-between` where it positions the first and last elements at start and end. And then consistent spacing between each element. I'd like something similar where each element is the ObservationKeyMarker+label. I would of course just use flexbox but this has to be in pure SVG as I have other code that inserts it into a canvas element.

[image]

Comment: use `text-anchor="middle"` and give text as x and y the calculated  "middle point"

Comment: @timbo: Still not clear, what you're trying to achieve. Please clarify, how the desired rendering should look like. You could add a snippet with your current svg output/result (e.g. does the posted screenshot match your requirements?).  I have the suspicion, you actually want to get an alignment  with distributed spaces between all label elements (including preceding icons/markers) – similar to css  flex `space-between`. Since your code is not plain svg, please add a `react` tag.

Comment: Thanks. Added tag & updated comment